# Converting internal go struct array to protobuf generated pointer array

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I'm trying to convert an internal type to the protobuf generated type and I can't get the array to convert. I'm new to go so I don't know all the methods that could help. But this is my attempt. When run this code I get

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>   [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x86c724]

along with a lot other byte data. I'm wondering what the best way to convert internal structs to the protobufs is. I think I'm having the most trouble with the protobuf generated code being pointers.

Proto Definitions

```
message GameHistory {
  message Game {
    int64 gameId = 1;
  }

  repeated Game matches = 1;
  string username = 2;
}

message GetRequest {
  string username = 1;
}

message GetGameResponse {
  GameHistory gameHistory = 1;
}
```

Go Code

```
// GameHistory model
type GameHistory struct {
  Game []struct {
    GameID     int64  `json:"gameId"`
  } `json:"games"`
  UserName   string `json:"username"`
}

func constructGameHistoryResponse(gameHistory models.GameHistory) *pb.GetGameResponse {

  games := make([]*pb.GameHistory_Game, len(gameHistory.Games))
  for i := range matchHistory.Matches {
    games[i].GameID = gameHistory.Games[i].GameID
  }

  res := &pb.GetGameResponse{
    GameHistory: &pb.GameHistory{
      Games:    games,
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `games` slice is initialized with nil values, as it's of type `[]*pb.GameHistory_Game` (slice of pointers to pb.GameGistory_Game - init value for pointer is nil). You want to access the `GameID` property of those elements. You should create them instead :

```
for i := range matchHistory.Matches {
    games[i]=&pb.GameHistory{GameID: gameHistory.Games[i].GameID}
}
```

Also, I recommend taking a look over the go protobuf documentation, as you have the [`Marshal`](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Marshal) and [`Unmarshal`](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Unmarshal) methods there for decoding and encoding protobuf messages.

Comment: I did want to use those methods but I can't find examples on how to properly use them. So just for my knowledge for go as well what do I need to do to set that value?

Comment: If you do not want to get the nil pointer dereference anymore you can start by setting the slice type to []pb.GameHistory_Game (is it GameHistory_Game or GameHistory tho?)

Comment: for `Marshal` you need an object of the type generated by compiling your protobufs in go code (with protoc), the method returns a byte slice which stores the message. And for `Unmarshal` you need the byte slice which stores the protbuf message and an object of the the type generated by compiling your protobufs in go code (with protoc), eg. err := proto.Unmarshal(protoMessageBytes, objectToStoreDecodedDataInto)

Comment: you can also do this to keep `games` as type slice of pointers and do this instead `games[i]=&pb.GameHistory{GameID: gameHistory.Games[i].GameID}`. I think this is what you want

Comment: Well GameHistory_Game is the object generated with proto and the GameHistory has a struct Game that matches that. The problem is my data is coming to a go struct first then it is going to the proto generated struct. I looked at converting my Go struct to a byte array slice first but wasn't sure that was the correct approach.

Comment: Yep the last comment with `games[i]=&pb.GameHistory{GameID: gameHistory.Games[i].GameID}` was what I needed thanks. I would love to get the marshal to work though so I'll look into that. Thanks much